# Function to sum numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum each number in column A with each one in column according to the following rule to get the number in column C.

Rule:

- The first number in A plus the last number in column B to get the fist number in column C
- The second number in A plus the second last number in B to get the second number in C
- And so on

Could anyone help me to write the function to do this?

What I can do is manually write a function for each sum for example A1 + B5, A2 + B4,...

However, that is not what I want. I want something that can apply for all.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What I can do is manually write a function for each sum for example A1 + B5, A2 + B4,... However, that is not what I want. I want something that can apply for all.

Comment: <shrug>. By the way there is a mistake in your diagram ...

Comment: Just a typo though, instead of `4+6` the user has written `3+6`...

Answer (score 2):

Let's split this into two problems.  One is doing the math you describe.  The other is automating the parameters.  Doing the math is easy if you specify the number and location of the rows.  It gets complicated if you want a generic formula that includes determining those parameters.

So let's assume your array starts in A1.  We'll stick the row count, 5 in this case, in D1.  And to keep it simple, let's ignore handling blanks and other complications.  Assume you have a correctly prepared block of data and that you manually copy the formula in column C just where you need it.

You could use this formula in C1 and then copy it down to the other cells:

```
=A1+INDIRECT("B"&$D$1+1-ROW())
```

The INDIRECT function creates a cell reference from text and math.

Another method would be to use the INDEX function:

```
=A1+INDEX(B$1:B$5,$D$1+1-ROW(),1)
```

This hard codes the data range into the formula, which may not be desirable.  INDEX returns the value from the specified range given a row and column relative to the range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you also want to do this with macros, but here is an example with a macro.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    Dim num1 As Integer, num2 As Integer, counter As Integer, amountOfRows As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    amountOfRows = ws.Range("B1", ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    num1 = Range("A1").Value
    num2 = ActiveCell.Value

       For counter = 1 To amountOfRows

          Cells(counter, 3) = num1 + num2

            If counter = 5 Then
            Exit Sub
            End If

          num1 = Range("A1").Offset(0 + counter, 0).Value
          num2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-counter, 0).Value


        Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Getting into VBA Editor to write a macro**

Depending on what version of VBA using you can use this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2010.php) to find out how to add VBA macro in excel.

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor - right click on Sheet 1(Sheet1) and select `Insert Module`

---

**Macro for your requirement - cross addition**

You can use the following macro to do your cross_addtion as demonstrated by your picture.

```
Sub cross_addition()
' find out the last cell in a series
a = Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
For i = 1 To a
    For j = a To 1 Step -1
        k = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(j, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 3) = k
        i = i + 1
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The macro assumes that the data that you want to add are in columns A and B and column C would be the output column.  So, please modify the code as per your requirements.